# How can I clear console while running program in CLION

Tags: c, macos, terminal, clion

Is it possible to clear the terminal while running the app in CLION? Operating system - macOS

I have tried **system("clear");** and **system("cls")**

**EDIT:** With system("cls") it prints out *sh: cls: command not found*. And with system("clear") nothing happens. I also included *<stdlib.h>* library.

```
void gameAlgorithm(int difficulty)
{
    int number = rand() % difficulty;
    int guess = -1;

    while(guess != number)
    {
        printf("\nYour guess?: ");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        if(guess < number)
        {
            printf("Number is HIGHER than %d.", guess);
        }else if(guess > number)
        {
            printf("Number is LOWER than %d.", guess);
        }
        system("clear");
    }
    printf("\nYOU ARE CORRECT!!!");
}
```

I wanted to learn about clearing the terminal while running the program. This is a basic "guess number" game. Each iteration has to clear the terminal (as I thought).

I have tried to run *main.c* in the terminal and it works fine. But is it possible to make the same thing on CLION?

Comment: You tried and what happened?

Comment: `system("clear");` works on Linux. Should probably work on MacOS too. Post your code.

Comment: system("clear") doesn't give any warning, so I think it should work.

Comment: try a simpler program, like one `printf` and `system("clear")` and see if it works.

Comment: And yeah, add newlines to your prints (in the *end* of the output, not the beginning). The output buffering might give weird effects.

Comment: Wait, so you are asking about the CLION built-in console? That might be be a different story. It might not be supporting clearing.

Comment: Try `printf("\033[H\033[J");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods to clear the console or output screen and one of them is `clrscr()` function. It clears the screen as the function invokes. It is declared in `conio.h` header file.

Comment: `conio.h` is Windows stuff isn't it?  It seems that OP is on macos

Comment: `clrscr()` isn't MSVC. IIR it is in Borland Turbo C's `conio` library. Are you teaching/studying computing history?

Comment: `clrscr()` works in Turbo c++ compiler..for GCC compiler ,use `system("clear")`

Answer (score 0):

To run in Clion and make the console behave like a traditional console, you can check the box called "**Emulate terminal in the output console**" in your applications "Run/Debug Configuration" options screen.

I think I saw that this was introduced sometime in the 2023 releases.